# project structure for building java installer using install4j

Tags: install4j

I'm evaluating install4j to create my Java app installers for windows and using Maven to build project.

I have parent Maven project(Installer) and maven module (frontend-installer).
I have created a dummy .install4j file and included in frontend-installer.
C://Program Files//install4j6
${project.basedir}//sample.install4j

Then tried to compile with "mvn install4j:compile".
Build is successful.
However it is complaining about some missing media files.

Now I have some questions.

What are the files required?
what should be the Project structure?

Comment: projectFile : ${project.basedir}//sample.install4j                                                                  install4j.home :  C://Program Files//install4j6

Answer (score 0):

> dummy .install4j file

install4j is not taking all the required information to build the installer from your maven POM, because that information is not contained there. So taking about a "dummy" .install4j file does not make sense. You have to use the install4j IDE to define your installer according to your requirements.

> However it is complaining about some missing media files.

In the install4j IDE, go to the media section and add at least one media file.